# What is a metering frequency and why would an airport have it?

Tags: radio-communications, ground-operations, frequency

I just read a post from a pilot complaining about how he thought a metering frequency was useless.  It has something to do with being on the ground at an airport.

What is it, what purpose does it serve, and what causes an airport to adopt one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use of a metering controller and frequency at an airport is one strategy used to prevent congestion on ramps and taxiways. When ready for push back from the gate, pilots call metering. The metering controller will typically either give them permission to push with a ground frequency to call when ready for taxi, or they will tell them to monitor a particular ground frequency for permission to push. They may even tell the pilots to stay on the gate and call back after a specified delay. The use of metering allows the airport controllers to manage ramp and taxi space by sequencing aircraft push and taxi.

Metering control can also help manage potential congestion due to ground delays for situations such as poor weather, runway closures, deicing, flow times into particular destination airports or any other situation that increases taxi time or slows down departures.

Some airports uses different strategies such as discrete ramp areas and frequencies to coordinate push back and taxi flow or internal coordination between controllers.

Answer (score 2):

In order to see metering in action, use http://liveatc.net and monitor the metering freq during bad weather like falling snow, typically at a northern airport like KMSP. Departure ATIS ( not arrival ATIS) will direct all flights to use the metering freq and then the metering freq asks if the flight needs deice. If it does, then metering directs the flight to a deice pad, if it doesn't, it approves it for push back and then tells it to call ground control for taxi.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever driven into a freeway on-ramp and ran into a traffic light that tells drivers when they can proceed? It's usually turned on during rush hour to prevent jams and accidents. Same thing. It's a flow control method. That pilot was probably unhappy at how long he/she had to wait to be handed over to Ground Control so they could pushback/taxi after contacting the controller on the metering frequency.

Comment: "Have you ever driven into a freeway on-ramp and ran into a traffic light that tells drivers when they can proceed?" No, I haven't. Could you explain in a bit more detail what exactly the metering frequency is actually used for?

Comment: If you are in the air... *A fix along an established route from over which aircraft will be metered prior to entering terminal airspace. Normally, this fix should be established at a distance from the airport which will facilitate a profile descent 10,000 feet above airport elevation [AAE] or above.* On the ground, metering is a process by which you call a controller on a freq NOT ground control, and that controller puts you in a queue to contact ground control when they are ready for you. It's flow control. :)

Comment: Would be nice if you could add that last description to your answer

Comment: @J.Hougaard You're welcome to edit the answer. :)

Comment: @J.Hougaard With respect to roadways, see [Ramp meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramp_meter). They're not common in the US and quite rare in the rest of the world.

Comment: @MichaelHampton In some states, such as California, they are very common.